# Setting value of variable on button event listener

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want the value of a variable named button_name to be set on a button event listener and send it in URL as REQUEST parameter. But what is happening the host variable is set on page load and does not take the value of updated variable. Any idea how to set the value of the variable dynamically and send it as REQUEST parameter?

```
var button_name;

 $.Settings(
 {  
    host : 'http://my_server_Address/abc.php?filename='+button_name,
 })

 function name_setter(name)
{
button_name=name;
}

<input type='button' onclick="name_setter('click_me')" value='click_me'/>
```

Please suggest if you think it can be done in some other way.

Comment: What the heck is `$.Settings`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling `$.Settings`, the `host` string is being evaluated right then and there.  At that point `button_name` is `undefined`.

Changing the `button_name` variable later on won't have any affect, since the string was already evaluated.

Check to see if the `host` parameter can accept a function instead of just a string.

Comment: Hazmat thanks,Yes you are right same is happening but i want to set the button_name on listener and then it should go to php file.

Comment: @Ali: You're gonna have to move the `$.Settings` call *inside* the click handler, so that the string is evaluated at the right time.